# getrows method of the recordset object does not call in sequence

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, recordset

Calling Oracle SP which fills the data in the record set.

Fetching rows through the recordset `getrows()` method.

When called the `getrows` method and pass a function for fetching the inner methods always run in the end.

The first method calls the inner method, and the inner method received the data, and recordset is being send to inner function.

Example  in below code functioncall method return empty data and then `responseObj.push` run. After this the `getrows` method process.

```
function lookups(req, res, next) {
    rows = functioncall(context);
    responesObj.push({ "Return Data": rows });
}

function simpleProcedureExecute(query, bindvars, opts = {}) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    oracledb.getConnection(
        conn,

        function (err, connection) {
            if (err) throw err;
            connection.execute(
                query,
                bindvars,
                function (err, result) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.error(err.message);

                        reject(err);
                    }
                    procJson = [];
                    function processResultSet() {

                        console.log("internal method");
                        console.log(result.outBinds.result);
                        try {

                            result.outBinds.result.getRows(1000, function (err, rows) {

                                if (err) console.log(err);

                                if (rows.length) {
                                    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                                        procJson.push({});
                                        for (var j = 0; j < result.outBinds.result.metaData.length; j++) {
                                            procJson[i][result.outBinds.result.metaData[j].name.toLowerCase()] = rows[i][j];
                                        }
                                    }


                                    processResultSet();
                                    return;

                                }
                                resultSet.close(function (err) {
                                    if (err) console.error(err.message);

                                    conn.release(function (err) {
                                        if (err) console.error(err.message);
                                    });
                                });
                            });

                        }
                        catch (err) {
                            console.log(err);
                        }


                    }
                    processResultSet();
                }

            );
        }
    );
    resolve(procJson);
});
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most obvious issue is the timing of when you're resolving the promise - which is way too soon. You're invoking `resolve` outside of the call to `oracledb.getConnection`. You don't have the connection yet, haven't executed the query yet, and haven't collected the rows yet. You have to do all of that first, then invoke `resolve` and pass along the data.

This is one of the harder things to wrap your head around when you're new to Node.js. See this video, it may help some: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iAdeljxq_hs&t=0s&index=2&list=PL_lVOJzXeE__1Kh3ko0F-39-cpNLPXbJL

Also, see this series which covers different async patterns in Node.js. Most Node.js developers start with callbacks and then move to alternative patterns for async work: https://jsao.io/2017/06/how-to-get-use-and-close-a-db-connection-using-various-async-patterns/

Finally, here's an example of how one can iterate a result set with async/await:

```
const oracledb = require('oracledb');
const config = require('./dbConfig.js');

async function runTest() {
  let conn;
  let result;

  try {
    conn = await oracledb.getConnection(config);

    result = await conn.execute(
      'select * from all_objects where rownum < 100',
      [],
      {
        resultSet: true
      }
    );

    let row;

    while (row = await result.resultSet.getRow()) {
      console.log(row);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  } finally {
    if (result && result.resultSet) {
      try {
        await result.resultSet.close();
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
    }

    if (conn) {
      try {
        await conn.close();
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
    }
  }
}

runTest();
```

Depending on the workload, it may be better to get more rows at once with `getRows`:

```
const oracledb = require('oracledb');
const config = require('./dbConfig.js');

async function runTest() {
  let conn;
  let result;

  try {
    conn = await oracledb.getConnection(config);

    result = await conn.execute(
      'select * from all_objects where rownum < 100',
      [],
      {
        resultSet: true
      }
    );

    let rows = await result.resultSet.getRows(50);

    while (rows.length) {
      for (let x = 0; x < rows.length; x += 1) {
        console.log(rows[x]);
      }

      rows = await result.resultSet.getRows(50);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  } finally {
    if (result && result.resultSet) {
      try {
        await result.resultSet.close();
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
    }

    if (conn) {
      try {
        await conn.close();
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
    }
  }
}

runTest();
```

Comment: Thanks Dan. You reply gave me direction to use getrows directly without calling inner function and it helps a lot. So I did my work as per below code which is working fine now.

Answer (score 1):

After getting direction from Dan to use getrows directly without calling inner function. Find below my code to resolve it.

```
async function simpleProcedureExecute(query, bindvars, opts = {}) {
let rowss;
let conn;
let procJson = [];
try {
    conn = await oracledb.getConnection();
    result = await conn.execute(query, bindvars);
    rowss = await result.outBinds.result.getRows(1000);
    if (rowss.length) {
        for (var i = 0; i < rowss.length; i++) {
            procJson.push({});
            for (var j = 0; j < result.outBinds.result.metaData.length; j++) {
                procJson[i][result.outBinds.result.metaData[j].name.toUpperCase()] = rowss[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    return procJson;
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
} finally {
    if (conn) { // conn assignment worked, need to close
        try {
            await conn.close();
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    }
}
}
```